# What were the sequence of events which led to this line up for the Fantastic Four?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, the-incredible-hulk, wolverine, ghost-rider

I just came across this Fantastic Four cover online.

I don't know a huge amount about the Fantastic Four, but this line up looks odd to me...

[image]

**Can anyone tell me how this came to be?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This occurs when a Skrull named De'Lilah comes to Earth in search of an old artifact, and is being pursued by Mole Man.

In an effort to buy herself some time, she kidnaps the Fantastic Four and then uses Reed Richard's equipment to summon four nearby heroes, and tells them that the Fantastic Four were killed by Mole Man and his army. There seems to be no specific rhyme or reason that they were chosen other than convenience.

[image: come to me, my not FF]

Spider-Man is in town, of course. Hulk and Wolverine just happen to be in town too - for some reason.

[image: what are you guys doin here?]

And, hey - why not Ghost Rider too?

[image: vroom vroom!]

De'Lilah is looking for an egg.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great answer Phantom, thanks :D

Comment: “An egg, Richards, an egg such as you have never *dreamed* of!” This summer’s Fantastic Four movie would have been immeasurably improved by the inclusion of that line somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

When it seemed that the Fantastic Four had died, Wolverine, Spiderman, Hulk and Ghost Rider joined together to avenge the seemingly-deceased team.

Actually the Fantastic Four were captured by Skrulls, and tricked into fighting Mole-Man so the Skrulls could steal something from him. First appearance was Fantastic Four #347.

Comment: Four heroes, teaming up to avenge their fallen friends. If only we could think up a good name for the group.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The Revengers. That's legally distinct enough right?? Can't sure me for that!